# Read 300MB binary file to char array

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to load binary file into char array. My code:

```
int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1 000 000
FILE *f;
char buffer[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
f = fopen("sample.bin", "rb"); //sample.bin is 300MB binary file
if (f)
  n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), MAX_FILE_SIZE, f);
```

It works until I set `MAX_FILE_SIZE` to anything bigger than 1M because I recieve `program.exe has stopped working`. If I thinking right to load all `sample.bin` to memory I should set `MAX_FILE_SIZE` to ~300M. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not a testable example, but I suspect you run out of stackspace.

Comment: Use some heap allocated memory (e.g. `malloc`).

Comment: Have you tried making your buffer `static`? This will allocate the space in the data segment instead of the stack

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no C syntax for defining large numbers with separators for blocks of digits: `int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1 000 000` should be written `int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1000000;`.

Allocating a large array as a local object with automatic storage may cause undefined behavior.  The total space available for this depends on the system, but may be less than one megabyte.  I suggest you allocate the buffer with `malloc()` and free it after use:

```
size_t MAX_FILE_SIZE = 300000000;  // 300MB

int read_file(void) {
    FILE *f;
    int n = -1;
    char *buffer = malloc(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return -1;
    f = fopen("sample.bin", "rb"); //sample.bin is 300MB binary file
    if (f) {
        n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), MAX_FILE_SIZE, f);
        // perform what ever task you want
        fclose(f);
    }
    free(buffer);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your platform and compiler, some limits are set on allowable allocations on stack (that's where your buffer goes). If you want to load the entire file into memory, you would have to use the heap (use malloc). So instead of:

```
char buffer[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
```

use:

```
char *buffer;
if ((buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_FILE_SIZE)) == 0) {
    // exit or some other action to take as your OS failed to allocate
}
```

Comment: This exact code wont work well because `buffer` will go out of scope immediately if the condition is not met.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks.